# Error compiling many source files on Linux

Tags: c, linux, compiler-errors

I am having trouble compiling in Linux and I am doing exactly the same as many other threads and books have suggested but can not understand my error.  Here are my source files:  main.c, process_info.c, and process_info.h

For now I am ignoring the correctness of my code because I am trying to compile it to see if it works and fix errors and they come about (I am very new to Linux and haven't done any debugging without using an IDE).

To compile my source on Mint Linux 17 - Cinnamon, I am trying this to the terminal:

```
gcc main.o process_info.o -o newmain

main.o: In function `main':
main.c:(.text+0x26): undefined reference to `readFile'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

And I also tried doing:

```
gcc -Wall  main.c process_info.c -o newmain

/tmp/ccnBKqCu.o: In function `main':
main.c:(.text+0x26): undefined reference to `readFile'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I don't know why I am getting the error since I thought I was doing things right.

Below is the content of my source files (the code inside isn't correct but under testing):

```
/******************************************************************
*
* File: main.c
* Description: Main file to execute code
*
*******************************************************************/
#include "process_info.h"

int main() {

    char *msg;
    char msg_buffer[MAX_BUFF_SIZE];
    char file_buffer[MAX_BUFF_SIZE];
    int fileDes[FILE_DESC_SIZE];

    readFile(file_buffer);

    msg = "hello world\n";
    pipe(fileDes);

     if (fork() == IS_CHILD) {
        // This is the child process
         printf("child process: \n");
         write(fileDes[WRITE_INDEX], msg,MESSAGE_SIZE );
     exit(0); // ends process

     }

     // This is the parent process
     read(fileDes[READ_INDEX],msg_buffer, MESSAGE_SIZE);
     write(WRITE_INDEX,msg_buffer, MESSAGE_SIZE);

return 0;

}

/******************************************************************
*
* File: OS_Proj1.h
* Description: OS Fork and Pipe Project header
*
*******************************************************************/
#ifndef PROCESS_INFO_H
#define PROCESS_INFO_H

#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define MAX_BUFF_SIZE  1024 // common value
#define FILE_DESC_SIZE 2
#define IS_CHILD       0
#define MESSAGE_SIZE   12
#define READ_INDEX     0
#define WRITE_INDEX    1
#define PERMISSION     0
#define FILE_DIR_1      "/workspace/CSCI_474/Project1/filedat1"
#define FILE_DIR_2      "/workspace/CSCI_474/Project1/filedat2"
#define FILE_DIR_3      "/workspace/CSCI_474/Project1/filedat3"
#define FILE_DIR_4      "/workspace/CSCI_474/Project1/filedat4"
#define FD_ERROR       -1

// Function prototypes
void readFile(char *buffer);


#endif


/******************************************************************
*
* File: process_info.c
* Description: Main file to execute code
*
*******************************************************************/
#include "process_info.h"
#include <fcntl.h>

void readFIle(char *buffer){ 
  int fileDesc;
  char filename[] = FILE_DIR_1 ;

  fileDesc = open(filename,O_RDONLY,PERMISSION);

  // test if file opened successfully
  if(fileDesc == FD_ERROR){
    perror("Cannot open output file\n");
    exit(1);
  }
  // read the file if it opened successfully
  else {
    while(  read(fileDesc,buffer,MAX_BUFF_SIZE) > 0  ) {
      write(WRITE_INDEX,buffer,MAX_BUFF_SIZE);
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: You should compile your source files with `gcc -Wall -g` (then use the `gdb` debugger)

Comment: When the linker complains that it can't find a symbol you know you have defined, always check spelling first.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, thanks for the advice I'm ashamed that I didn't catch that, I'm so used to being explicitly yelled at by IDEs I didn't notice that problem.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, I'll take a look at what -g is research on how to use gdb. Thanks.

Comment: @user1945925: You were "*yelled at*" by the compiler this time, so what? ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

very simple :)

You have readFIle defined but declaration name is readFile and you are trying to call it which has no definition. Check the spelling of both.

Comment: can not believe I missed the most basic troubleshooting task....i didn't notice since I am used to being yelled at by the IDE when things like that happen.

Answer (score 3):

```
readFIle

readFile
```

SO demands I enter more text, so here it is.

Comment: Thanks it seems like everyone caught this really quick, I up-voted your response but I gave it to the guy below since he answered first.